# Understanding Angular Import Statements

Tags: angular, angular5

I m new to Angular and ES6 model of writing code. I have been reading through articles on angular modules and import statement and have got few questions

I m from .NET background and could relate import statements in the components, services etc

For example,

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


  getIncidentData(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get('incidents.json');
  }
```

- I m importing HttpClient module and using its  service in my code.. Or Simply, to use any methods defined in other classes, we need to import it first.. So its understandable
- And also in the NgModule decorative, in the import statement, we import them.. Because an angular module (as a feature) defines what are the modules that can be used by its components, services etc..

Here are my questions

- At the module level , we do the import statement, but actually we are not using any methods or variables from them in that place, rather we use it at the individual components, services only.. Why do we need to define it over there?
- And if we define it at the module level, do we need to repeat it at the component level as well. In the below example, I imported HttpModule at appModule, do I need import it in the service? Will the components, service inherit modules import automatically?
- Most external modules have name that ends with “module” but some don’t have how do we know that it’s a module or component or service?

Here is some sample

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { UitkModule } from '@uimf/uitk';
    import { TableModule } from '@uimf/uitk/components/tables';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { CardComponent } from './card/card.component';
```

Comment: These links should answer several of your questions. Take a look! https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-vs-jsmodule
https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping
https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Comment: @Stevethemacguy yes.. i went through it but little bit confused. could you give some more information

Comment: I'll try to come back and answer your questions directly, but I probably won't have time before next week. Just wanted to help point you in the right direction for now!

Comment: Check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions

At the module level , we do the import statement, but actually we are not using any methods or variables from them in that place, rather we use it at the individual components, services only.. Why do we need to define it over there?

> - Modules are like a container for multiple components
> - Component level: Only need to import the components you need (from the module you imported)

And if we define it at the module level, do we need to repeat it at the component level as well. In the below example, I imported HttpModule at appModule, do I need import it in the service? Will the components, service inherit modules import automatically?

> - Only if you called it in your code
> - Highlight then Ctrl + Space -> will import the module automatically. But, sometimes automatic import will import the wrong path. You need
>     to do your research.

Most external modules have name that ends with “module” but some don’t have how do we know that it’s a module or component or service?

> - Metadata are used to determine which is which.
> - A lot of times naming standards are implemented. Like adding service at the end of the class name. For e.g. BaseService
> - **@Injectable()** -> most probably a service
> - **@NgModule** -> module
> - **@Component** -> component

Check out the tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7016839/jen  #jen Thanks for the explanation. Just couple of questions. In my project, i imported Observable in the component but not imported it at the module level..  Similarly i m importing MatTableDataSource at the component level not at the module level and MatTableModule at the module level not at the component level and common module included both in the component and module. The way i see it in my project might be wrong as well but would like to know the exact logic behind it.

Comment: Observables are declarative (another different kind of problem). MatTableDataSource is a class (can't really import classes / component in the modules). As for MatTableModule, only **modules** can be imported in a module level. What do you use the common module for in the component level?

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is, we import modules alone at the app module level. and classes at the component level. But my doubt started when the CLI adding the import appcomponent from  components automatically at the app module level..

Comment: In addition, If i need a observable at the component, should i need to import it at the component level or not. And also Would be correct to say, modules need to be imported at module level and the classes within the module needs to be imported at the component level.

Comment: For the Observable, you need to just import it to the component level. For the classes, yes you can just import in the component level. If you get confused you can always serve the Angular app. It'll tell you more or less if you need to import something in the Module level.

Comment: Would appreciate it if you voted for my answer as useful :)

Comment: Thanks Jen. Unfortunately i opened stackflow account recently and i have 6 points so far. i couldnt upvote something unless i reach 15 points. thats the settings they have included in stackoverflow